# How to turn the duplicate part in my code to a checking function?

Tags: python-3.x, function

I come up a solution for leetcode "5. Longest Palindromic Substring" with parts of duplicate codes. One of good ways to solve duplicate code is to make a function. How do I write my check here to a function? I am confused what I should return to make both variables - longest and ans - being updated. Thanks!

The part of duplicate code:

```
if len(s[l:r+1]) > longest:
    longest = len(s[l:r+1])
    ans = s[l:r+1]
```

Full code:

```
class Solution:
    def longestPalindrome(self, s: str) -> str:
        if len(s) == 0:
            return ''
        if len(s) == 1:
            return s

        longest = 0
        ans = ''

        for pos in range(len(s)-1):
            l, r = pos, pos
            if pos > 0 and pos < len(s) - 1 and s[pos-1] == s[pos+1]:
                l, r = pos-1, pos+1
                while l > 0 and r < len(s) - 1 and s[l-1] == s[r+1]:
                    l -= 1
                    r += 1

                # duplicate code 1
                if len(s[l:r+1]) > longest:
                    longest = len(s[l:r+1])
                    ans = s[l:r+1] 


            if s[pos] == s[pos+1]:
                l, r = pos, pos+1
                while l > 0 and r < len(s) - 1 and s[l-1] == s[r+1]:
                    l -= 1
                    r += 1

                # duplicate code 2
                if len(s[l:r+1]) > longest:
                    longest = len(s[l:r+1])
                    ans = s[l:r+1] 


        if ans == '' and len(s) > 0:
            return s[0]

        return ans
```

Answer (score 0):

The if statements and while loops before the duplicate code blocks are mostly duplicated as well, as is using the `longest` variable to keep track of the length of `ans` when you already have `ans` -- here's one way you could simplify things via another function:

```
class Solution:
    def find_longest(self, s, left, right):
        if s[left] == s[right]:
            if right - left + 1 > len(self.ans):
                self.ans = s[left:right + 1]
            if left > 0 and right < len(s) - 1:
                self.find_longest(s, left - 1, right + 1)

    def longestPalindrome(self, s: str) -> str:
        if len(s) == 1:
            return s

        self.ans = ''

        for pos in range(len(s) - 1):
            self.find_longest(s, pos, pos)
            self.find_longest(s, pos, pos + 1)

        return self.ans
```